# Manually convert embedded documents to references in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a book document that has array field containing authors documents, I decide to normalize the data and create "authors" collection. How do I retrieve the author detail, and how do I add it to the a new collection called "authors", then reference it within the array in books collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MongoDB** accomplishes relationships through **embedded documents** completely different approach as compared to conventional relational database which encapsulates a feature of **foreign key** through which it references data across another table in database.

According to above mentioned description as a solution to it please try executing following query in mongodb to extract details of specific author

```
db.collection.find({ authors: { $elemMatch: { firstname: "Kristina", lastname:'Chodorow' } } },
   { authors: { $elemMatch: { firstname: "Kristina", lastname:'Chodorow' } } }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy you can create authors collection , every collection generate unique id and when ever you create a book collection you have to find authors id from its details (like firstname) and place it in book collection as author_id

like ....

```
 [authors: {
            id:"54385-ab4f5-c356-bf38"
            firstname: "Kristina",
            lastname: "Chodorow",
        }

]
```

like in node.js

```
domain.author.find{{author.firstname:"Kristina",author.lastname:"Chodorow"},function(err,data){
console.log(data.id)}}
```

and book

```
{
        title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
        published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
        pages: 68,
        language: "English",
        authors_id: 54385-ab4f5-c356-bf38
    }
```